# Mixing code documentation with code by appending various notes to sections?

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, documentation-generation, code-documentation

Consider the following minimal example:

---

## `docs/index.rst`

```
* :ref:`modindex`
```

## `docs/modules.rst`

```
exampleproject
==============

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   exampleproject

.. print_notes_attached_to_topic::
   :topic: notes_about_someproblem
```

## `docs/conf.py`

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']
```

## `docs/exampleproject.rst`

```
exampleproject package
======================

Module contents
---------------

.. automodule:: exampleproject
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

## `exampleproject/__init__.py`

```
def example_fun():
    """
    This is the docstring I'll be discussing.
    .. attach_to_topic::
       :topic: notes_about_someproblem
       
       Grass is green.
    """
    pass

def other_example_fun():
    """
    This is the second docstring I'll be discussing.
    .. attach_to_topic::
       :topic: notes_about_someproblem
       
       Sky is blue.
    """
    pass
```

---

I know that `sphinx.ext.autodoc` can extract docstrings and put them within docs/exampleproject.rst. My question is: is there a way to also automatically append some sections to specific documents? Ideally I'd like to put as much as possible of my documentation in the source code, then use the source files of the documentation to put that information in a linear order. Something like:

1. in example_fun docstring in `exampleproject/__init__.py`, write expression "add a note to a section/topic named building_methods saying 'before running the project, do xyz'"
2. in index.rst, "list all notes tied to a section/topic named building_methods".

---

## Comparison to autodoc

I know that sphinx has `sphinx.ext.autodoc` that processes docstrings of applications. The problem is that autodoc forces a certain "code-first" / "API-first" structure of the documentation. What I'm looking for is a solution that will let me keep as much of the documentation in the code as possible and then turn this documentation into a linear document, with data about certain topics extracted from something like the example `attach_to_topic` directive.

---

Is this possible with sphinx?

Comment: What is "building_methods"?

Comment: @mzjn some example section I'd like to define and extend from multiple points scaterred throughout the source code. Does this make sense?

Comment: Sorry, to me this is unclear. I don't understand what you mean by "define and extend from multiple points scaterred throughout the source code". The minimal example does not help. It does not demonstrate anything interesting.

Comment: Sphinx provides events that can be used to process docstrings before generating the final output:  https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#docstring-preprocessing. Is it something like that you are looking for?

Comment: @mzjn I edited both my question and the example to compare what I'm looking for to sphinx.ext.autodoc. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with mzjn that your example doesn't give much to go on, but I'll hazard a couple of guesses:

**Appending to apidoc stub pages**

The `docs/exampleproject.rst` and `docs/modules.rst` stub files get generated automatically by [sphinx-apidoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html).
Then you manually append your own content (a `.. print_notes_attached_to_topic::` directive) into those.

This will be problematic, because every time `sphinx-apidoc` extracts the Python docstrings to rebuild its stub pages, your chunk is overwritten/lost.
I'd never try and mix my own content into pages owned/generated by an extension - they can sit side-by-side, but separate, e.g. put all your directives in a `./docs/all-my-print-notes.rst` page.

That said, if you want to complicate your life, then post-process.  Amend the Sphinx [makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) to detect stub page changes and trigger a Bash or Python script that plops your custom content on the end.
Cleanest if done indirectly -- a single [include](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#including-an-external-document-fragment) directive goes in the stub page so that your custom content can remain isolated elsewhere.

The [Jinja2 templates](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html#cmdoption-sphinx-apidoc-0) for `autodoc` and `autosummary` (in `./site-packages/sphinx/templates/apidoc/` & `./site-packages/sphinx/ext/autosummary/templates/`) offer limited customization, but really only good for layout and static content.

**Your Sphinx extension**

The functionally you want sounds a lot like [sphinx.ext.todo](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/todo.html).  Your `.. attach_to_topic::` directives are scattered throughout the Python module docstrings (equivalent to `.. todo::` directives) and your `.. print_notes_attached_to_topic::` directives collect up those chunks into "a linear order" (equivalent to `.. todolist::`).

Luckily for you, the [docs about creating extensions](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/tutorials/todo.html) gives that very example which you can adapt to your needs.  Your extension will have one extra feature, because it provides a `:topic:` option to tag/classify each `.. todo::` item, and also to limit the scope of each `.. todolist::` collation.

Comment: "stub files get generated automatically by sphinx.ext.autodoc" - That is confusing. Do you mean "generated by [sphinx-apidoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html)"?

Comment: I just want to point out that using sphinx-apidoc is not mandatory. The files with `automodule` directives can be created manually.